# Get newline stats for a text file in Python

Tags: python, newline

I had a nasty CRLF / LF conflict in git file that was probably committed from Windows machine. Is there a cross-platform way (preferably in Python) to detect what type of newlines is dominant through the file?

I've got this code (based on idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10562258/239247):

```
import sys
if not sys.argv[1:]:
  sys.exit('usage: %s <filename>' % sys.argv[0])

with open(sys.argv[1],"rb") as f:
  d = f.read()
  crlf, lfcr = d.count('\r\n'), d.count('\n\r')
  cr, lf = d.count('\r'), d.count('\n')
  print('crlf: %s' % crlf)
  print('lfcr: %s' % lfcr)
  print('cr: %s' % cr)
  print('lf: %s' % lf)
  print('\ncr-crlf-lfcr: %s' % (cr - crlf - lfcr))
  print('lf-crlf-lfcr: %s' % (lf - crlf - lfcr))
  print('\ntotal (lf+cr-2*crlf-2*lfcr): %s\n' % (lf + cr - 2*crlf - 2*lfcr))
```

But it gives the stats wrong (for [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/techtonik/spyder/7d819e5dc293103eca1ba1c6c1196489a16d5bd1/spyderlib/widgets/explorer.py)):

```
crlf: 1123
lfcr: 58
cr: 1123
lf: 1123

cr-crlf-lfcr: -58
lf-crlf-lfcr: -58

total (lf+cr-2*crlf-2*lfcr): -116
```

Comment: Like sorrat, I get 1123 crlf pairs for that file, with 0 for the 3 other EOL markers.

Comment: @PM2Ring I need a better test file. I thought that this one actually contained mixed linefeeds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import sys


def calculate_line_endings(path):
    # order matters!
    endings = [
        b'\r\n',
        b'\n\r',
        b'\n',
        b'\r',
    ]
    counts = dict.fromkeys(endings, 0)

    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            for x in endings:
                if line.endswith(x):
                    counts[x] += 1
                    break
    print(counts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        calculate_line_endings(sys.argv[1])

    sys.exit('usage: %s <filepath>' % sys.argv[0])
```

Gives output for your file

```
crlf: 1123
lfcr: 0
cr: 0
lf: 0
```

Is it enough?

Comment: This one is good. Do you know how the `line in open(filename, "rb"):` detects the lines correctly? Just to know about corner cases.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. May be the cause in [PEP-278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)

Answer (score 2):

The posted code doesn't work properly bcause Counter is counting characters in the file - it doesn't look for character pairs like `\r\n` and `\n\r`.

Here's some Python 2.6 code that finds each occurrence of the 4 EOL markers `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\r` and `\n` using a regex. The trick is to look for the `\r\n` and `\n\r` pairs before looking for the single char EOL markers.

For testing purposes it creates some random text data; I wrote this before I noticed your link to a test file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Find and count various line ending character combinations

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/29695861/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.04.17
'''

import random
import re
from itertools import groupby

random.seed(42)

#Make a random text string containing various EOL combinations
tokens = list(2*'ABCDEFGHIJK ' + '\r\n') + ['\r\n', '\n\r']
datasize = 300
data = ''.join([random.choice(tokens) for _ in range(datasize)])
print repr(data), '\n'

#regex to find various EOL combinations
pat = re.compile(r'\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n')

eols = pat.findall(data)
print eols, '\n'

grouped = [(len(list(group)), key) for key, group in groupby(sorted(eols))]
print sorted(grouped, reverse=True)
```

**output**

```
'FAHGIG\rC AGCAFGDGEKAKHJE\r\nJCC EKID\n\rKD F\rEHBGICGCHFKKFH\r\nGFEIEK\n\rFDH JGAIHF\r\n\rIG \nAHGDHE\n G\n\rCCBDFK BK\n\rC\n\r\rAIHDHFDAA\r\n\rHCF\n\rIFFEJDJCAJA\r\n\r IB\r\r\nCBBJJDBDH\r FDIFI\n\rGACDGJEGGBFG\n\rBGGFD\r\nDBJKFCA BIG\n\rC J\rGFA HG\nA\rDB\n\r \n\r\n EBF BK\n\rHJA \r\n\n\rDIEI\n\rEDIBEC E\r\nCFEGGD\rGEF EC\r\nFIG GIIJCA\n\r\n\rCFH\r\n\r\rKE HF\n\rGAKIG\r\nDDCDHEIFFHB\n C HAJFHID AC\r' 

['\r', '\r\n', '\n\r', '\r', '\r\n', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\n', '\n', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\n\r', '\r', '\n', '\r', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\n', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\r\n', '\n\r', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\r', '\r', '\n\r', '\r\n', '\n', '\r'] 

[(17, '\n\r'), (14, '\r'), (12, '\r\n'), (5, '\n')]
```

---

Here's a version that reads the data from a named file, following the pattern of the code in the question.

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
import sys

if not sys.argv[1:]:
    exit('usage: %s <filename>' % sys.argv[0])

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

print repr(data), '\n'

#regex to find various EOL combinations
pat = re.compile(r'\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n')

eols = pat.findall(data)
print eols, '\n'

grouped = [(len(list(group)), key) for key, group in groupby(sorted(eols))]
print sorted(grouped, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Nice approach. Especially cool that it has test data to compare.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, I would recommend to check if you have the following case:
`\r\n\r\n\r\n`. Following your code this will count the following:

```
crlf: 3 -- [\r\n][\r\n][\r\n]
lfcr: 2 -- \r[\n\r][\n\r]\n
cr: 3   -- [\r]\n[\r]\n[\r]\n
lf: 3   -- \r[\n]\r[\n]\r[\n]

cr-crlf-lfcr: -2
lf-crlf-lfcr: -2

total (lf+cr-2*crlf-2*lfcr): -4
```

As you can see some `\n`'s and some `\r`'s are counted twice for `crlf` and `lfcr`. Instead you can just read line by line and count the line endings `line.endswith()`. To get exact statistics for `cr` and `lf` then you can count `\r\n` and `\n\r` as cr+1 and lf+1.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with line endings in git is to use git configuration. You can define what exactly must be done to line endings globally, in a particular repository or for specific files. In `.gitattributes` file, you can define that certain files must be converted to the native line endings of your system for each checkout, and converted back at checkins. See [GitHub line endings help](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for a detailed description.

Comment: I don't want to convert anything, Can git just leave my files as-is by default?