# How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My attempt to programmatically create a dictionary of lists is failing to allow me to individually address dictionary keys. Whenever I create the dictionary of lists and try to append to one key, all of them are updated. Here's a very simple test case:

```
data = {}
data = data.fromkeys(range(2),[])
data[1].append('hello')
print data
```

Actual result: `{0: ['hello'], 1: ['hello']}`

Expected result: `{0: [], 1: ['hello']}`

Here's what works

```
data = {0:[],1:[]}
data[1].append('hello')
print data
```

Actual and Expected Result: `{0: [], 1: ['hello']}`

Why is the `fromkeys` method not working as expected?

Comment: I think you should call `list()` to actually create a new list each time. You might want to use dict comprehension rather than `fromkeys`

Answer (score 148, accepted):

When `[]` is passed as the second argument to `dict.fromkeys()`, all values in the resulting `dict` will be the *same* `list` object.

In Python 2.7 or above, use a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951) instead:

```
data = {k: [] for k in range(2)}
```

In earlier versions of Python, there is no dict comprehension, but a list comprehension can be passed to the `dict` constructor instead:

```
data = dict([(k, []) for k in range(2)])
```

In 2.4-2.6, it is also possible to pass a generator expression to `dict`, and the surrounding parentheses [can be dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297653):

```
data = dict((k, []) for k in range(2))
```

Answer (score 124):

Try using a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
data[1].append('hello')
```

This way, the keys don't need to be initialized with empty lists ahead of time. The `defaultdict()` object instead calls the factory function given to it, every time a key is accessed that doesn't exist yet. So, in this example, attempting to access `data[1]` triggers `data[1] = list()` internally, giving that key a new empty list as its value.

The original code with `.fromkeys` shares *one* (mutable) list. Similarly,

```
alist = [1]
data = dict.fromkeys(range(2), alist)
alist.append(2)
print(data)
```

would output `{0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2]}`. This is [called out in the `dict.fromkeys()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object such as an empty list.

Another option is to use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which retrieves the value for a key after first checking it exists and setting a default if it doesn't. `.append` can then be called on the result:

```
data = {}
data.setdefault(1, []).append('hello')
```

Finally, to create a dictionary from a list of known keys and a given "template" list (where each value should start with the same elements, but be a distinct list), use a dictionary comprehension and *copy* the initial list:

```
alist = [1]
data = {key: alist[:] for key in range(2)}
```

Here, `alist[:]` creates a shallow copy of `alist`, and this is done separately for each value. See [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802) for more techniques for copying the list.

Answer (score 45):

You could use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> keys = ['a','b','c']
>>> value = [0, 0]
>>> {key: list(value) for key in keys}
    {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0]}
```

Comment: `value[:]` isn't _that_ ugly (unless you share Alex Martelli's aesthetic sense :) ), and it's less typing. In recent versions of Python there's now a `list.copy` method. In terms of performance, slicing is fastest for small lists (upto 50 or 60 items), but for larger lists `list(value)` is actually a little faster. `value.copy()` seems to have similar performance to `list(value)`. All 3 techniques dramatically slow down for large lists: on my old 32 bit machine that happens around 32k, YMMV depending on your CPU's word size and cache sizes.

Answer (score 44):

This answer is here to explain this behavior to anyone flummoxed by the results they get of trying to instantiate a `dict` with `fromkeys()` with a mutable default value in that `dict`.

Consider:

```
#Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 

# start by validating that different variables pointing to an
# empty mutable are indeed different references.
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = []
>>> id(l1)
140150323815176
>>> id(l2)
140150324024968
```

so any change to `l1` will not affect `l2` and vice versa.
this would be true for any mutable so far, including a `dict`.

```
# create a new dict from an iterable of keys
>>> dict1 = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], [])
>>> dict1
{'c': [], 'b': [], 'a': []}
```

this can be a handy function. 
here we are assigning to each key a default value which also happens to be an empty list.

```
# the dict has its own id.
>>> id(dict1)
140150327601160

# but look at the ids of the values.
>>> id(dict1['a'])
140150323816328
>>> id(dict1['b'])
140150323816328
>>> id(dict1['c'])
140150323816328
```

Indeed they are all using the same ref!
A change to one is a change to all, since they are in fact the same object!

```
>>> dict1['a'].append('apples')
>>> dict1
{'c': ['apples'], 'b': ['apples'], 'a': ['apples']}
>>> id(dict1['a'])
>>> 140150323816328
>>> id(dict1['b'])
140150323816328
>>> id(dict1['c'])
140150323816328
```

for many, this was not what was intended!

Now let's try it with making an explicit copy of the list being used as a the default value.

```
>>> empty_list = []
>>> id(empty_list)
140150324169864
```

and now create a dict with a copy of `empty_list`.

```
>>> dict2 = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], empty_list[:])
>>> id(dict2)
140150323831432
>>> id(dict2['a'])
140150327184328
>>> id(dict2['b'])
140150327184328
>>> id(dict2['c'])
140150327184328
>>> dict2['a'].append('apples')
>>> dict2
{'c': ['apples'], 'b': ['apples'], 'a': ['apples']}
```

Still no joy!
I hear someone shout, it's because I used an empty list!

```
>>> not_empty_list = [0]
>>> dict3 = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], not_empty_list[:])
>>> dict3
{'c': [0], 'b': [0], 'a': [0]}
>>> dict3['a'].append('apples')
>>> dict3
{'c': [0, 'apples'], 'b': [0, 'apples'], 'a': [0, 'apples']}
```

The default behavior of `fromkeys()` is to assign `None` to the value.

```
>>> dict4 = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> dict4
{'c': None, 'b': None, 'a': None}
>>> id(dict4['a'])
9901984
>>> id(dict4['b'])
9901984
>>> id(dict4['c'])
9901984
```

Indeed, all of the values are the same (and the only!) `None`.
Now, let's iterate, in one of a myriad number of ways, through the `dict` and change the value.

```
>>> for k, _ in dict4.items():
...    dict4[k] = []

>>> dict4
{'c': [], 'b': [], 'a': []}
```

Hmm. Looks the same as before!

```
>>> id(dict4['a'])
140150318876488
>>> id(dict4['b'])
140150324122824
>>> id(dict4['c'])
140150294277576
>>> dict4['a'].append('apples')
>>> dict4
>>> {'c': [], 'b': [], 'a': ['apples']}
```

But they are indeed different `[]`s, which was in this case the intended result.

Comment: So we have to iterate?

Comment: i thought the whole point was to not iterate ... that's the shortcut , otherwise why do i need this function in the first place ?

Comment: Of course you have to iterate. `dict.fromkeys` iterates in the first place. Anyway, this seems like a lot of detail to explain something that's already pretty clear from the top two answers.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d = dict((k, [0, 0]) for k in l)
```

Answer (score 9):

You are populating your dictionaries with references to a single list so when you update it, the update is reflected across all the references. Try a dictionary comprehension instead. See
[Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

```
d = {k : v for k in blah blah blah}
```

Comment: great suggestion on initializing dictionary values... thanks cobie! I extended your example to reset the values in an existing dictionary, d. I performed this as follows:
    d = { k:0 for k in d }

Comment: What is `v` in this answer?

Comment: Sure, but page 262 of no less than the 5'th edition of Learning Python makes no reference to this business of deliberately creating a dict with just one single reference in common to all keys such that there can only ever be one value in the entire dict. Nowhere can I find any clue as to what is the purpose of fromkeys(). Who would ever want a dict where all the values are the same? How can you force the single common reference to later separate into unique references such that you can later populate unique values to the keys? Python is such a great language, but this one is a rare puzzler.