# Append value to one list in dictionary appends value to all lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary, append

**The Problem**

I am creating a dictionary with empty lists as values in the following way.

```
>>> words = dict.fromkeys(['coach', 'we', 'be'], [])
```

The dictionary looks like this.

```
>>> words
{'coach': [], 'be': [], 'we': []}
```

When I append a value to one list, the value is appended to all of them as in this example.

```
>>> words['coach'].append('test')
{'coach': ['test'], 'be': ['test'], 'we': ['test']}
```

**The Question**

My question has two parts. First, why is this happening? Second, what can I do about it? That is, how can I append a value to only one list?

I imagine that in creating the dictionary, I made all lists point to the same object. But I don't understand how that can be because when I input `0` instead of `[]` in dictionary creation and then add values instead of append them, the values behave differently as if they point to distinct objects.

I would appreciate any input. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721/how-do-i-initialize-a-dictionary-of-empty-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys` uses the *same object* for all values, in this case a `mutable` list... That means, all keys share *the same empty list*... When you try to `.append` to the value of one list, the changes are made in-place to the object, so changes to it are visible by all that reference it.

If instead you used a dict-comp, eg: `{k:[] for k in ['could', 'we', 'be']}` each `[]` is a *different empty list* and so would be unique for each key value and work as expected.

In regards to using `dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], 0)` the `0` is an *immutable* object thus isn't subject to that gotcha as changes to it result in new objects, not a change to the underlying object which different names (in this case - the values of the different keys) may share.