# Does dict.fromkeys assign the same reference over and over?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, reference

I tried to create the perfect dictionary for my needs (dict that's containing a dict with values and a list). However it seems that I assigned the same reference over and over.

```
brands = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
infoBrands = dict.fromkeys(brands,
                dict(dict.fromkeys(['nbOffers', 'nbBestOffers'], 0),
                     **dict.fromkeys(['higherPrice'], [])))

infoBrands['val1']['nbOffers'] += 1
print infoBrands
```

Here the results:

```
{'val3':
     {'higherPrice': [],
       'nbOffers': 1,
       'nbBestOffers': 0},
  'val2':
       {'higherPrice': [],
        'nbOffers': 1,
        'nbBestOffers': 0},
  'val1':
       {'higherPrice': [],
        'nbOffers': 1,
        'nbBestOffers': 0}
}
```

As you can see, val1, val2 and val3 refer to the same dict.
I'm not sure how I should handle it?
Any tips?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` uses the same value for every key, hence the reference issue. Have you looked into `collections.defaultdict` at all? (See e.g. http://bugs.python.org/issue6730)

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, thank you for the tip. i'm going to look at that right away

Comment: Or you could use dict comprehension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397153/append-value-to-one-list-in-dictionary-appends-value-to-all-lists-in-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is commonly done with [*dictionary comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries) rather than`dict.fromkeys()`:

```
brands = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
infoBrands = {brand: {'nbOffers': 0, 'nbBestOffers': 0, 'higherPrice': []}
                for brand in brands}

infoBrands['val1']['nbOffers'] += 1
print infoBrands
```

Output:

```
{'val3': {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 0, 'nbBestOffers': 0},
 'val2': {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 0, 'nbBestOffers': 0},
 'val1': {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 1, 'nbBestOffers': 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of achieving the required result using [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
brands = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
infoBrands = {g: dict({i: 0 for i in ['nbOffers', 'nbBestOffers']},
                       **{j: [] for j in ['higherPrice']}) for g in brands}

infoBrands['val1']['nbOffers'] += 1
print infoBrands
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brands = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
init = dict(higher_price=[], nb_offers=0, nb_best_offers=0)
info = {brand: dict(init) for brand in brands}
```

Comment: This will make separate dictionaries, but they'll share `higher_price` lists, e.g. `info["val1"]["higher_price"] is info["val2"]["higher_price"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone,

EDIT: look at @martineau answer

I did the following:

```
brands = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
infoBrands = dict.fromkeys(brands)

for brand in brands:
    infoBrands[brand] = dict([('nbOffers', 0), ('nbBestOffers', 0), ('higherPrice', [])])                                                                                                                                                     

infoBrands['val1']['nbOffers'] = 1
print infoBrands
```

Results:

> {'val3': {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 0, 'nbBestOffers': 0},
>   'val2': {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 0, 'nbBestOffers': 0}, 'val1':
>   {'higherPrice': [], 'nbOffers': 1, 'nbBestOffers': 0}}