# Python dictionary set all values to class object

Tags: python, class, dictionary

After having created a dictionary from one dataframe column as keys, I want to set all values to an instance of an object (the class serves as container for storing key statistics for each row of the original pandas dataframe).

Hence, I tried this:

```
class Bond:
    def __init__(self):
        self.totalsize = 0
        self.count = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    isin_dict = list_of_isins.set_index('isin').T.to_dict()
    isin_dict = dict.fromkeys(isin_dict, Bond())
```

The problem is that all values in `isin_dict` point to the same address, ie all rows share the same `Bond` class object.
How could I create a dictionary with each key holding a separate class instance as value?

Comment: what is `list_of_isins` ?

Comment: `list_of_isins` is a dataframe consisting of one column

Comment: What about a dict recursion? `isin_dict = {key: Bond() for key in isin_dict}` NOTE: this may not work directly as I'm not familiar on how to iterate over pandas DF, but I assume it works as you have used it for `dict.fromkeys()` that expects an iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759062/does-dict-fromkeys-assign-the-same-reference-over-and-over)

`dict.fromKeys()` **uses the same value for every key**.

The solution is to use dictionary comprehensions or to use `defaultdict` from collections module.

Sample Code to use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict    

class Bond:

    def __init__(self):
        pass        

# I have just used your variable and stored in a list
d = defaultdict(lambda : list(list_of_isins.set_index('isin').T)    

for keys in d:
    d[keys] = Bond() 

print (d)
```

The reason we are passing the type `dict` to `defaultdict` is the first argument should be callable for `defaultdict`. Else you may get a TypeError

Alternately you may also pass a lambda expression which will make it callable

Comment: thanks to @DineshKumar, with dictionary comprehension it works and each row has its own class instance

Comment: @SuperMartingale  I am glad it helped. you may also use defaultdict is you wanna simplify the code. I will leave the implementation to you :)