# why does appending to list in dictonary have different results?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

*Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]*

```
my_list = ["a","b","c"]

dict_one = {key:[] for key in my_list}
print(dict_one)
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}

dict_two = dict.fromkeys(my_list, [])
print(dict_two)
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}

dict_one['a'].append('some_data')
dict_two['a'].append('some_data')

print(dict_one)
{'a': ['some_data'], 'b': [], 'c': []}

print(dict_two)
{'a': ['some_data'], 'b': ['some_data'], 'c': ['some_data']}
```

I excpected the same result for dict_one and dict_two.
Could anyone please explain the difference ?

Comment: Also: [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509721/7851470)

Comment: Also: [Append value to one list in dictionary appends value to all lists in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23397153/7851470)

Answer (score 7):

It's a variation on [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1126841)
.

`fromkeys` does not create a new empty list for each value it adds to the dict it is building; it uses the *same* (mutable) value you provided as the second argument.

---

As an aside, it would be nice if there was a way to provide a factory to use to produce the value; then you could write

```
dict_three = dict.fromkeys(my_list, factory=lambda: [])
```

analogous to how `defaultdict` takes a function to produce the initial value for a new key:

```
d = defaultdict(list)  # *not* d = defaultdict([])
```