# Appending to one list in a dictionary instead appends to all lists

Tags: python, list, append

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, edges=[]):
...         self.edges = edges
>>> G = {'x': [A(), A()], 'y': [A(), A()]}
>>> G['y'][0].edges.append(7)
>>> G['y'][0].edges
[7]
>>> G['x'][0].edges
[7]
```

Why is it when appending to `G['y'][0].edges` it also appends to all other lists. I found this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397153/append-value-to-one-list-in-dictionary-appends-value-to-all-lists-in-dictionary) but I can't tell if it is happening because of the same reason or not.