# Appending in nested arrays causes all arrays to be appended

Tags: python

Possible dupe: [Append value to one list in dictionary appends value to all lists in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397153/append-value-to-one-list-in-dictionary-appends-value-to-all-lists-in-dictionary)

I've encountered a problem in using nested arrays, where all elements are updated, when I only want to append to a specific index.

```
x = [[]] * 6
x[0].append(1)
# expected: [[1], [], [], [], [], []]
# result: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

What I'm guessing is that `x[0]` returns `[]`, which turns the statement to `[].append(1)` and updates all empty lists. This is supported by the fact that non-empty sets will not be changed.

```
x = [[]] * 6
x[1] = [0]
x[0].append(1)
# [[1], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

I currently do this workaround to assign the value:

```
x = [[]] * 6
y = x[0].copy()
y.append(1)
x[0] = y
```

I want to understand 1) why python would evaulate the `x[0]` bit and make `[].append()` apply to multiple elements in the list, if my theory is correct and 2) if there is a better way to add values in a nested list.

Comment: Try to change this `x = [[] for _ in range(6)]` and see the difference.  And it's helpful to see what's the `difference` in https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Related: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: _"This is supported by the fact that non-empty sets will not be changed"_: 1. There are no sets here, only lists. Terminology is important, because `set` is actually a thing in python whose behavior is distinct from a `list`. 2. Your statement is not true. E.g., try with `x = [[1]] * 6`

Answer (score 0):

In line `x = [[]] * 6`, you creating a list `x` with `6` reference to the same inner list `[]`. To make it simple, `x = [[]] * 6` is equivalent to:

```py
inner_list = []
x = []
for _ in range(6):
    x.append(inner_list) # here same 'inner_list' is appended 6 times
```

So, what you want to do here is:

```py
x = []
for _ in range(6):
    inner_list = []
    x.append(inner_list) # here you are creating 6 different 'inner_list' and appending it to 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `x = [[]] * 6` creates a list with 6 references to the same list. Thus, when you append an element to any of them, the others are also updated.

When you say `x[1] = [0]`, you've replaced x[1] entry with a new list. Thus, when updating another entry this new list will not be updated.

If you want to create a list that consists of 6 independent lists, do
`[[] for _ in range(6)]`

Answer (score 0):

In python, list, dict, set, tuples are collection data types.  It means, if you declare a variable based on collection, you have the address of the collection.

If you duplicate a collection, you have the same address for every duplication.  It is the case when you do it: x = [[]] * 6

If you modify one element, it affects all of his copies.