# How do I initialize a dictionary with a list of keys and values as empty sets in python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using `dict.fromkeys([1,2,3],set())`. This initializes creates the dictionary but when I add a value to any one of the sets all the sets get updated!

```
>>> d=dict.fromkeys([1,2,3],set())
>>> d
>>> {1: set(), 2: set(), 3: set()}
>>> d[1].add('a')
>>> d
>>> {1: {'a'}, 2: {'a'}, 3: {'a'}}
```

It seems that all the three values of the dictionary are referring to the same set. I want to initialize all the values of the dictionary to empty sets so that I can perform some operations on these sets in a loop based on the keys later.

Comment: See also `defaultdict` - you can create a dict that will automatically create an empty set for you for each new key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721/how-do-i-initialize-a-dictionary-of-empty-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using dictionary comprehension

```
d = {x: set() for x in [1, 2, 3]}
```

Or using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Great! That works. But I thought the `fromkeys()` should be doing the same thing. Can you explain whats going on in the case of `fromkeys()`.

Comment: `set()` is only invoked *once* in the `fromkeys()` call. The DC calls it *each time*.

Comment: Then I don't see the point of `fromkeys()` function other than maybe using it for the case where the initializing value is an atomic type like numeral or None.

Comment: @Dhruv Precisely, if you want to have mutable values you usually use a `defaultdict` which saves you the trouble of initializing in the first place, or a dict comprehension if initialization is important in itself or depends on the keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> d[1].add('a')
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {1: {'a'}})
>>> d[2].add('b')
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {1: {'a'}, 2: {'b'}})
```

The way it works, is, when you try to add a value to a key like `dict[key].add(value)`, it checks whether the key is present; if so, then it adds the value to the set. If it is not present the value is added as a `set` since the default is set  as a `set` (`defaultdict(set)`).

Answer (score 1):

You want a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) **so you don't need to initialize the sets** in the first place:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
# That's it, initialization complete. Use goes like this:
>>> d[1].add('a')
>>> d[2].add('b')
>>> d[3].add('c')
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {1: {'a'}, 2: {'b'}, 3: {'c'}})
```