# Appending to a list inside a dict value referring to only one key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a dict that holds string keys and list values, initialized like this:

```
names = ['first name', 'second name', 'last name']
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(names, [])
```

What I need now is to append a list to a specific key, which I am trying to do like so:

```
for result in results:
    my_dict[names[0]].append(result.mean())
```

As this code is inside another loop, I need to loop through the index in name inside my_dict keys and append to each a different list, which should result in something like this:

```
>>>my_dict
Output: 
{'first name': [1,
  34,
  52,
  2,
  54,
  3],
 'second name': [4,
  22,
  11,
  3,
  -9,
  1],
...]}
```

But the problem is even though I specify only one key, I get the same values in every key of this dict, like so:

```
>>>my_dict
Output: 
{'first name': [1,
  34,
  52,
  2,
  54,
  3],
 'second name': [1,
  34,
  52,
  2,
  54,
  3],
...]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721/how-do-i-initialize-a-dictionary-of-empty-lists-in-python)

Comment: When you use `dict.fromkeys(keys, some_object)` then all the keys are referring to the same object. Don't do that

Comment: This appears to be the exact same problem I have, and it answers my question perfectly. Thanks a million