# Why is the python append method not modifying the list referenced in this dictionary?

Tags: python

So I am iterating through a "list of lists" of integers in python 3.9.0 as follows:

```
n = 3
adjList = dict.fromkeys([i for i in range(n)], [])
p = [[1, 0], [2, 0]]
for s, e in p:
   if e not in adjList[s]:
     adjList[s].append(e)
```

I would expect adjList to result in:

```
{0: [], 1: [0], 2: [0]}
```

Instead I get:

```
>>> adjList
{0: [0], 1: [0], 2: [0]}
```

Why isn't append modifying the list specified in adjList[i] only where i is the integer key?

I can get it to work by changing `adjList[s].append(e)` to `adjList[s] = adjList[s] + [e]`.

Comment: What does your debugger say `adjList` is after the *first* call to `append`?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` uses the *same list object* for each `dict` value, causing the problem described in the linked duplicate. You can instead use a dict comprehension to build the dictionary: `{i: [] for i in range(n)}`.

Comment: Do `adjList = {i: [] for i in range(n)}`

Comment: While it does answer the question, I don't think the current linked question is the corrected dup. It doesn't say anything about `fromkeys` and why it shouldn't be used in this instance. The appropriate dup should be [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509721/1040092)

Comment: @Wondercricket I changed it