# Add value in dictionary with inner dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, append

Could you please help with the following problem.
I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{'logtype16777217': {'Table_AmfSetID.csv': [],
  'Table_QCI.csv': [],
  'Table_body.csv': [],
  'Table_head.csv': [],
  'Table_AmfPointer.csv': [],
  'Table_AmfRegionID.csv': []},
'logtype16777218': {'Table_AmfSetID.csv': [],
  'Table_QCI.csv': [],
  'Table_body.csv': [],
  'Table_head.csv': [],
  'Table_AmfPointer.csv': [],
  'Table_AmfRegionID.csv': []},
...}
```

So I want to make kind of a catalogue.
I created an empty dict (logtype_files_library) with the described structure, and then loop over my files and want to add each of them into corresponding list.

filenames -  is simply a list of file paths like

```
['/mnt/c/Users/d00858421/Downloads/csv-N800/0010_logtype16777217_File.csv',
 '/mnt/c/Users/d00858421/Downloads/csv-N800/0010_logtype16777217_Table_AmfPointer.csv',
 '/mnt/c/Users/d00858421/Downloads/csv-N800/0010_logtype16777217_Table_AmfRegionID.csv', ...]
```

```
    for file in filenames:
        file_logtype = [i for i in file.split('/')[-1].split('_') if i.startswith('logtype')][0]
        table_type = '_'.join(file.split('/')[-1].split('_')[2:])
        logtype_files_library[file_logtype][table_type].append(file)
```

And this is not working. Instead of adding file into corresponding list by two keys, it appends everything everywhere. What's wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When *I* run this on the provided data, I get `KeyError: 'File.csv'`.  If I fix that, it seems to work fine.  Issue might be how you created `logtype_files_library`?

Comment: How did you create your dictionary? Is it possible that you've inadvertently set every value to the **same** empty inner dict object, rather than a new empty object each time?

Comment: For example, if you had done something like `logtype_files_library=dict.fromkeys(logtypes, template_inner_dict)` you'd see this problem, because `logtype_files_library[file_logtype]` would be accessing the same inner dict object every time.

Comment: Hello! @slothrop, you are right, that is how I created that dict.  ```logtype_files_library=dict.fromkeys(logtypes, dict.fromkeys(tables, []))``` Could you please say then how should I have done it correct?

Comment: Dictionary comprehension is a nice concise way to do this: `logtype_files_library={k1: {k2: [] for k2 in tables} for k1 in logtypes}`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721/how-do-i-initialize-a-dictionary-of-empty-lists-in-python (though not an exact duplicate, because that doesn't have the second layer of inner dicts)