# How to eliminate items in list of lists in fast way while imposing some restrictions on its items?

Tags: python, list, optimization

My very first post and question here...

So, let `list_a` be the list of lists:

```
list_a = [[2,7,8], [3,4,2], [5,10], [4], [2,3,5]...]
```

Let `list_b` be another list of integers: `list_b = [5,7]`

I need to exclude all lists in `list_a`, whose items include at least one item from `list_b`.  The result from example above schould look like `list_c = [[3,4,2], [4]...]`

If `list_b` was not a list but a single number `b`, then one could define list_c in one line as:

```
list_c = [x for x in list_a if not b in x]
```

I am wondering, if it is possible to write an elegant one-liner also for the list `list_b` with several values in it.  Of course, I can just loop through all `list_b`'s values, but may be there exists a faster option?

Comment: I can see you have various answers at bottom. But as a dev, I would like to point out something, you should try to escape as much as writing one liner coding. In the beginning its always seems like its wonderful, but when troubleshooting, it would be much more hard to find out and maintain.

Comment: I agree with your point, but in this particular case I don't want to write one-liner for the sake of its own. I have to do this operation millions of times with lists contatinig up to 100000 lists as items, so every tiny cut in execution time helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first consider the task of checking an individual element of `list_a` - such as `[2,7,8]` - because no matter what, we're conceptually doing to need a way to do that, and then we're going to apply that to the list with a list comprehension. I'll use `a` as the name for such a list, and `b` for an element of `list_b`.

The straightforward way to write this is using the `any` builtin, which works elegantly in combination with generator expressions: `any(b in a for b in list_b)`.

The logic is simple: we create a generator expression (like a lazily-evaluated list comprehension) to represent the result of the `b in a` check applied to each `b in list_b`. We create those by replacing the `[]` with `()`; but due to a [special syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297653/python-generator-expression-parentheses-oddity) we may drop these when using it as the sole argument to a function. Then `any` does exactly what it sounds like: it checks (with early bail-out) whether any of the elements in the iterable (which includes generator expressions) is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false).

---

However, we can likely do better by taking advantage of set intersection. The key insight is that the test we are trying to do is symmetric; considering the test between `a` and `list_b` (and coming up with another name for elements of `a`), we could equally have written `any(x in list_b for x in a)`, except that it's harder to understand that.

Now, it doesn't help to make a `set` from `a`, because we have to iterate over `a` anyway in order to do that. (The generator expression does that implicitly; `in` used for list membership requires iteration.) However, if we make a `set` from `list_b`, then we can do that once, ahead of time, and just have `any(x in set_b for x in a)`.

But that, in turn, is a) as described above, hard to understand; and b) overlooking the built-in machinery of `set`s. The operator `&` normally used for set intersection requires a `set` on both sides, but the named method `.intersection` does not. Thus, `set_b.intersection(a)` does the trick.

---

Putting it all together, we get:

```
set_b = set(list_b)
list_c = [a for a in list_a if not set_b.intersection(a)]
```

Comment: upvote for also going with set intersection + making me realise that I can pass a list to set.intersection instead of a set as I always assumed until now ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution.  I have checked regarding run time following three options:

1)  "Any"-Solution of Mark M: [l for l in A if not any(n in l for n in B)]
2)  Consequitive loop through list_B's values
3)  Set_b.Intersection-Solution of Karl Knechtel

It turned out that the run times of option 1) and 2) were comparable while third option was the fastest.  In my test examples  Set_B_intersection method was about 5 times faster!

Answer (score 4):

You can write the logic all sublists in A where none of the elements of B are in the sublist with a list comprehension like:

```
A = [[2,7,8], [3,4,2], [5,10], [4], [2,3,5]]

B = [5,7]

[l for l in A if not any(n in l for n in B)]
# [[3, 4, 2], [4]]
```

The condition `any(n in l for n in B)` will be true if any element, `n`, of `B` is in the sublist, `l`, from `A`. Using `not` we can take the opposite of that.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Mark's answer is good but hard to read.

FYI, you can also leverage sets:

```
>>> set_b = set(list_b)
>>> [l for l in list_a if not set_b.intersection(l)]
[[3, 4, 2], [4]]
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be the fastest way to solve the problem!