# Get sum of specific list elements

Tags: python

At my python application I want to get the sum of segment_upload_list but only for objects that are stored locally, so basically every entry starting with "/tmp/VODProcessing/".
This is how my full list might look like:

```
[['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s"]]
```

I wanted to get the sum like this:

```
totalsize = sum([os.stat(f).st_size for f in segment_upload_list[0]])
```

but `[0]` does not really make much sense here. How can I sum all local paths here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "sum of list" do you mean the sum of the file lengths of the files listed? Or perhaps the sum of the lengths of the file names?

Comment: Are you looking for `os.stat(f[1]).st_size`?

Comment: Okay, so you want to get the `[0]` element (not `[1]`) *of each inner list*? Think about the problem carefully. You want to iterate over `segment_upload_list`, right? What will each `f` element look like? How could you transform that into the value you want to use in the `os.stat(...).st_size` call? Now, put the pieces together.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's right! I just want to sum the local paths

Comment: As already described by @Brian I guess, set the position for each, but I guess it has to be os.stat(f[0]).st_size not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the pieces together logically:

```
   [                         for      in                    ]
```

We want to iterate over the outer list; each of the elements that is `in segment_upload_list` has something useful for us, and we'll give it a name.

```
   [                         for pair in segment_upload_list]
```

Within each of those pairs, the first value is the local name, and the second value is the remote name. Indexes start at zero, so we are interested in `pair[0]`. (Alternately, we could unpack the pairs into two separate variables, and only use the first.) We want to... do something with that.

```
   [        pair[0]          for pair in segment_upload_list]
```

We know from the existing code what we want to do with it, in fact: get the `st_size` out of the `os.stat` result for the path.

```
   [os.stat(pair[0]).st_size for pair in segment_upload_list]
```

Finally, sum those values. We don't actually need to build a list; we can instead use a *generator expression*, and take advantage of the [special syntax rule that lets us drop the redundant parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297653/python-generator-expression-parentheses-oddity).

```
sum(os.stat(pair[0]).st_size for pair in segment_upload_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
pth = [['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s"], ['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s', "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s"]]


print([i for p in pth for i in p if i.startswith('/tmp')])
['/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8', '/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s', '/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s', '/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s', '/tmp/VODProcessing/output/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s']
```

Another nice trick:

```
print([p for p in sum(pth,[]) if p.startswith('/tmp')])
```

That `sum(pth,[])` essentially flattens the nested lists to a single one.

For the `Music` path, you can do (provided that it is fixed at second position):

```
print([p[1] for p in pth])

["Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/master.m3u8", "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0007.m4s", "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0022.m4s", "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0030.m4s", "Music/D'can/Se Pone Mas/1 Se Pone Mas/a-flac/f-0001.m4s"]
```

Comment: Yes that looks like a useable result :D

Comment: Can you also show an example for the opposite? Where I only want to get the music path, but not via startswith, how to do it with the position?

Comment: Is the music part fixed at position 2 or can be at any position?

Comment: Yes it is, but it does not always start with "Music" but the position should always be [1]

Comment: So, my answer applies then.